# Office 365 - unable to deactivate

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013, office365

We are using Office 365 ProPlus 2013. A new user tried to activate their install and received the error that they had reached their install limit of 5 machines. Upon clicking the link the deactivate previous installs that appears in that error dialog, the user is taken to their Office software management tab. Usually, if the user has previous installs, they are listed here and the user is able to deactivate. However, in this case, previous installs do not appear and it seems something else may be the problem.

I am looking for any suggestions as to what may be the problem, thanks.

Comment: I would contact Microsoft in a case like this.  I assume the correct account is being logged into, you have tried multiple browsers, and logged into a currently activated device to see if the problem isn't something silly?

Comment: When you say a 'new'user. Do you mean a new Office 365 user? That did not download any previous copies on other machines?

Comment: Yes, a new 365 user that has not installed before. I have tried multiple browsers and had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Microsoft having an issue with the service
http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/172/p/199771/596766.aspx

Comment: providing links is fine but could u summarize it as answer?